# how to set button to center using html on codename one

Tags: java, android, html

I'm trying to design an android app with codename one and I'm using HTML on it. I'm trying to style submit button to center but I couldn't get it. I have tried to use `<style ="text-align:center;"> submit </style>`

**HTML**

```
<tr> <td colspan="2"> <button name="submit">Submit</button> </td> </tr>
```

How can I get this to respond?

Comment: Can you add the code which is not working?

Comment: S.spieker,I don't understand your comment

Comment: You have problems with your submit button, so I'm just asking if you could post the code which is not working.

Comment: <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>   so,i just want the button to align to the center

Answer (score 0):

You giving style wrong way. Try following ways.

You should learn how to give html [Style.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)

```html
<table><tr> <td colspan="2"> <button name="submit">Submit</button> </td> </tr><table>

<style > 
  
  td{
    text-align:center;
}
  
  table {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i've tried the code above but the button will disappear when i run it. it is codename one with extension .cn1ml

Comment: I thing some another css will affect it. You should post all css code and possible then create fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

if `margin:0 auto;` doesn't work try to find the right margin that can make your button to be aligned at the centre

```
<tr> <td colspan="2"> <button name="submit">Submit</button> </td> </tr>


<style>
table tr td input["button"]{

margin:0 auto;

}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just placed the browser component into the container in a way where it doesn't take up the entire form. Make sure the parent layout is `BorderLayout` and make sure you added the browser to the center.

Also make sure you are using a recent version of JDK 7 in the simulator (not JDK 8) otherwise you might fallback to the old `HTMLComponent` if you are using the `WebBrowser` class. That component was designed for J2ME and only supported a subset of HTML.

The other answers address the potential pitfalls in your HTML.